# Service unavailable. The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap-client

I'm using SoapClient with my PHP page to gather data from a third party. I have increased my max_execution_time to 50 seconds and I have stopped getting those errors in the logs. However, now I get the Service Unavailable error and nothing in the logs after about 32 seconds.

I've timed the soap calls to anywhere from 2 seconds to 10 seconds each and my script may make 4 or 5 of these calls per execution. If I drop one or two of the calls it executes just under 30 seconds without error. This makes me think there's something else in my server config that's dropping the connection. To see if it was the third party server I kept the same number of API calls that properly executed within 30 seconds and added a sleep(10) after each execution and it failed at 31-32 seconds.

Comment: does sound like an issue with the remote site and not your code.

Comment: what's the value for max_execution_time in your php.ini ? set it to 0 if it isn't already, or set it up using an htaccess file (just make sure your host is allowed to override) then try again. If the problem persists, check the logs from the webservice you are accessing.

http://us2.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: You may be hitting the service too often, and it is returning a generic 5xx error as a result. If you can share details about who the third party actually is, that might help. Do you get the error consistently or intermittently?

Comment: I set max_execution_time to 0 and memory_limit to 4gb Ram. It executes fine but fails when I add a "sleep(10)" to give it a delay - for testing. The fail is Service Unavailable with no log. I'm hitting the API the same number of times but when it fails I've added the sleep logic. I'm adding the sleep logic to simulate a longer execution when traffic is high.

Comment: Is it possible that I'm hitting some other limit in PHP such as max upload or input? I wouldn't think the returned XML would use any other config setting other than max_execution_time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out it was due to Rackspace's load balancer. It was defaulted to 30 seconds no matter what my server was set to beneath it. In the event anyone ever needs to use the API, here's the article: https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/89

Comment: Also check this page - detailing instructions on just updating the timeout https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/89